# How can i get wall post same as facebook using php

Tags: php, facebook, curl, domdocument, file-get-contents

maybe it not the correct question but i'm looking for help, i have use curl, DOMDocument, and file_get_contents to get a image tag as facebook do but i can't. [image]

some thing like this.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses specific Open Graph meta tags that publishers can use to suggest an image, title, and description for Facebook to use when sharing a URL.  You will want to load the HTML with DOMDocument, and then look for these tags.

Look for tags with `og:` in the name, like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.png" />
```

See also:  http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

Comment: Thank you for answer my question, but i mean on my page to do something like i said. i was trying to get like a test, same link from yahoo but i get just empty image. have you any idea?

Comment: @manout I just told you how to get that image URL.  If you have specific code that isn't functioning, you should ask a specific question with that code.

Answer (score 0):

My code look like this:
i'm trying to get image image from yahoo link just like test 
https://es.finance.yahoo.com/noticias/amazon-prev-vender-un-smartphone-200856947.html

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(isset($_GET['c_txt'])){
$url = $_GET['c_txt'];
if(curl_init($url)){
    $html = file_get_contents($url);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);

    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
           echo $tag->getAttribute('src') . "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

but the result looks like:

```
https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/b?  c1=2&c2=7241469&c7=es.finance.yahoo.com%2Fnoticias%2Famazon-prev-vender-un-smartphone-200856947.html&c5=1185584786&c15=$&cv=2.0&cj=1
https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/130307/expansion_header_article.png
https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png
https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png
https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png
https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png
https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png
https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png
https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png
https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/130711/masnoticiasen2.jpg
https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png
https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png
```

and not the image that display at facebook, the tag what i want is this one:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Brad for your time at same time was somebody alse asking a same at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165820/get-meta-description-title-and-image-from-url-like-facebook-link-sharing, and was sample as **get_meta_tags()**