# URL Parsing to get the relevant Image as well as content in PHP (similar to facebook Share URL function)

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, domparser, url-parsing

I'm writing a url parsing program which gets the url (may be anything ranging from a blog post to a wikipedia link) and gets the image from the html and some excerpt content.

I am using Simple HTML DOM Parser and I managed to get the image and content for only some blog post urls. But I am not sure how to make it work for atmost all types of urls.

Just out of curiosity I wanted to know what's the mechanism behind the facebook share thing where you type a url and it shows the relevant images and a little bit of content. I came across on Depth First Search Approach on the search for this problem.

I just need an approach on how I can make it work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

P.S : I get the relevant images and contents from a blog post url because I parse the html using static class names.

Comment: Here is an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165820/get-meta-description-title-and-image-from-url-like-facebook-link-sharing

Comment: @Oleg I've already referred to those answers! I don't mean to get the meta information instead when I get the whole html content, I need to know how can I get the exact relevant image to the post or the content. What I'm asking is for something like http://embed.ly